# A region must be a GeoJSON Polygon or LinearRing. Got: 'MultiPoint'

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to Google Earth Engine and was trying to run a script to get Landsat images of districts of India after having a fusion table of shapes of all districts.
GEE script is as:

```
var india = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1UDdgOCf8DoRJ9bVm-UVbR6CqxtkJToLQjTFd0r0Z','geometry')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('Name', 'India'))
    .geometry();
var district = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1_GTWq6xk3hMYl6LelMm8o3VlnoHH0bsFUzLiW3_i','geometry')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('district', district_name));
```

where district_name is a defined variable containing the name of a district

```
 var india_image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
    .filterBounds(india)
    .filterDate('2014-03-01', '2014-09-01')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    // .limit(500)
    .map(maskClouds)
    .median();
var district_image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
    .filterBounds(district)
    .filterDate(year + '-03-01', year + '-05-01')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .map(maskClouds)
    .median();
```

and then after performing few actions having no affect on any of the variables, I am exporting these images to my Google drive.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: input.clip(district),
  description: district_name + '_summer_' + year,
  folder : 'Project_data',
  maxPixels: 499295920080,
  scale: 30,
  region: district
});
```

But here after executing and pressing "RUN" button in "Tasks" pane of GEE, I am getting the error "A region must be a GeoJSON Polygon or LinearRing. Got: 'MultiPoint'"

Link to GEE script: [GEE script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d266b6cf57b050f1036faad0ce37033c)

What could have gone wrong and How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `distric.geometry().bounds()` or `district.union().bounds()` in the Export call.  Even better, just draw a nice, simple rectangle around the place you want.

Comment: I checked both district.geometry() and district.union() one after the other and got the same error "A region must be a GeoJSON Polygon or LinearRing. Got: 'MultiPoint'", please also explain what do you mean by drawing a simple rectangle @Nicholas

Comment: I have edited the answer with what I think is a fix.  Try appending `bounds()`.  This will return the bounding box of whatever is in that FeatureCollection.

Comment: tried 'district.union().bounds()' but got error: "district.union(...).bounds is not a function" on console. @Nicholas

Comment: The 'district' property is a geometry, so I don't see how your filter is going to work.  Second, you need to supply a polygon geometry to `Export.image`.  That is provided by `featureCollection.geometry()` or `featureCollection.union()`.  If you are filtering a `FeatureCollection`, you get another `FeatureCollection`, in which case you need to get the `first()` thing out, then call `bounds()` (you just need to cast to `ee.Feature`).  https://code.earthengine.google.com/b36b660ca1f7a877bb508e920ac10b27.  Please note the Docs tab, from which you can learn about the return types of these methods.